# i deploy django project in cpanel(namecheap) without base url others urls are not working

Tags: django

1. i deploy django project in cpanel(namecheap) without base url others urls are not working

Not Found
The requested URL was not found on this server.

Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

Comment: Maybe you should add a base url, else the dns server has no point to start

Comment: where to add base url in django?

Comment: In your project, you have to create a new view and link it to the home page. But I am not sure if this is the solution for your problem. I think you already have a base url, anything else doesn't make sense.

Comment: have you solve this issue?? I have same issue from last 5 days

Comment: we change the server